# `gio` command won't display `metadata::custom-icon` attribute

Tags: linux, metadata, gio, gvfs

I have set a custom icon for a directory (via the file manager). this should set the `metadata::custom-icon` attribute. however, `gio info <path>` does not show this attribute at all.

the following python script shows it though:

```
from gi.repository import Gio

attribute = 'metadata::custom-icon'
folder = Gio.File.new_for_path('/path/to/directory')
info = folder.query_info(attribute, 0, None)
print(info.list_attributes())
print(info.get_attribute_string(attribute))

# output:
# ['metadata::custom-icon']
# file:///path/to/icon.png
```

I am curious to find out why that might be.

Comment: The only possibility would be, that gio has a bug. Does this problem still persist? I guess there might have been an update.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered you problem, got the same error.
At last I found there were different "gio" in my Ubuntu.
The one that report "metadata::custom-icon not supported" was "/home/user/anaconda3/bin/gio", which was provided by annaconda3.

And there was another "/usr/bin/gio" provided by apt-get, which worked for me.

To  discover which one of "gio" you are using, just type "which gio" in bash to find out.
To fix the problem:

1. change $PATH to use system provided gio, or
2. use absolute path of '/usr/bin/gio'

Hope that works for you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already fix the problem but for the people of the future:

Are you writing correctly the command? It is very tricky to make it works, I had a lot of problems because the path of picture has a space and because of the slashes '/'.

The command should be like this example:
`gio set $HOME/Documents/C metadata::custom-icon file://$HOME/Pictures/App_Logos/C.png`

DO NOT USE SPACES!

I have created a bash script to change icons in bulk, [check it here](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2288902)